# visual studio 2013 aws toolkit deployment error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, visual-studio-2013, toolkit

I am trying to deploy a test mvc4 web application from visual studio 2013 to AWS by selecting "publish to AWS" and selecting "Single Instance Template" option to launch a t1.micro EC2 instance.  I keep getting the following error when I click Deploy:

Error deploying new application: Unhandled error during deployment: Deployment Failed: Detected error in deployment bucket preparation; abandoning deployment.

Any clues as to how to solve this please?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just realized that the user account I had configured on AWS to use with this application didn't have proper permissions.  Problem solved.  Thanks.